# In-app purchase issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have successfully used [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial for implementing In app purchases. However, it can´t use it. I don´t understand how to, for example, tell my ads not to appear if the user made the in app purchase I set up. Does anyone know how to do this?

I thought I could use the NSUserDefaults with productIdentifier, but how can I tell it what In app purchase, the user bought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user made your in App then set value in NSUserDefaults like this

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchase"];

        [userDefaults synchronize];
```

and where you show the ads then check user made in app purchage or not if user made in app purchases not show ads

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if(![userDefaults boolForKey:@"isPurchase"])
        {
             NSLog(@"Enter add start ");

          // Your Ads show code
        }
```

Comment: but where to put the first bit of code? when the user hits the buy button? or inside the productPurchased?

Comment: - (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification

Comment: Ok! I will try this! Thank you! I will mark your answer when I succeed =)

Answer (score 0):

> transaction.payment.productIdentifier

will give you the product identifier of your product. Go through that tutorial again and you will see this.